# How to use put method properly ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input 
 #title
(keyup.enter)="createPost(title)"
type="text" 
class="form-control">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts" class="list-group-item">
        {{ post.title }}
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" (click)="updatePost(post)">Update</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Angular:

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: any;
  url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get(this.url)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.posts = response;
    })
  }

----

updatePost(post: any) {
    this.http.put(this.url + '/' + post.id, JSON.stringify({ title: 'Example' }))
    .subscribe(response => {
        
    })
  }
```

How can I update the posts value at a given ID with the title 'Example'?
If I console.log(response) it returns just a ID, not a proper value.
Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they're expecting content-type application/json in request header. You can play with content-type and see result https://reqbin.com/o0tzomnc
But even if you specify content-type they will return only updated field. In your case - only title field